# JMeterTest and JMeterTestManager dependencies

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to exeucte a .jmx file through the java class, but JMeterTest and JMeterTestManager are not getting imported.
JMeter, as per my knowledge is itself a bundle of jar.
can anyone tell me if i need dependency(ies) for these two or not, iif yes the please do provide.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you need to include [org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-platform-integration/tree/master/test-automation-framework/org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions) to your project as these classes don't come with [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide to get started with creating a JMeter test purely in Java. You can also use [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src) project as a reference